# Javascript getting 'undefined' when issuing property inside property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JavaScript, I´m trying to access a property from a class that is inside another class. I´m getting `undefined` for the given access.

**Main example code:**

```
//MainClass

function MainClass() {
   this.childClass = new ChildClass();
}


//ChildClass

function ChildClass() {
   this.prop1 = "A";
   this.prop2 = "B";
}
```

**ExampleWidget.js:**

```
(function ($) {

    $.widget("myWidget", {

    _create: function () {
         this.mainClass = new MainClass();
    },

    doSomething: function (){
        this.mainClass.childClass.prop1 = "1"; 
        this.mainClass.childClass.prop2 = "2"; 

        alert(this.mainClass.childClass.prop1); // shows undefined
        alert(this.mainClass.childClass.prop2); // shows undefined

    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

How can I change and access the properties of the child class?

Comment: The only reasons I can think of why this would show `undefined` are  a) you actually assigned `undefined` b) `this.mainClass.childClass` is not extensible c) `childClass` is a primitive string, number or boolean. You  are not doing any of this in your example, so the problem must be something you don't show. Please post a complete example and provide a demo which replicates the issue.

Comment: In JQuery function when you create object mainClass what all properties you are getting?

Comment: Dnyanesh - didn´t get your point...

Comment: Problem solved. There was a mistype at the original code for the original variable name. It really works. Thanks all who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any issue and but it still remain to you as How you call doSomething method.

Here is the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/jx5xr2m0/5/

You have to make sure that you are using this to call doSomething.

```
function MainClass() {
   this.childClass = new ChildClass();
}


//ChildClass

function ChildClass() {
   this.prop1 = "A";
   this.prop2 = "B";
} 

(function ($) {

    $.widget("custom.myWidget", {

    _create: function () {
         this.mainClass = new MainClass();  
         alert('ok');
         this.doSomething();
    },

    doSomething: function (){
        this.mainClass.childClass.prop1 = "1"; 
        this.mainClass.childClass.prop2 = "2"; 

        alert(this.mainClass.childClass.prop1); // shows undefined
        alert(this.mainClass.childClass.prop2); // shows undefined

    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

How are `_create` and `doSomething` being invoked?  Because this is what is causing your problem.  My guess is that `this` is different when `_create` is invoked vs. `doSomething`.  `_create` is instantiating and setting the class on one object and then your alerts are looking for the props on a completely different object in `doSomething`.

Further proof is that the code is fine when written by itself with no outside callers:

http://jsfiddle.net/2v8gzc6n/3/